# AppHarbor updating project changes

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, appharbor

I made some bigger changes to my MVC4 project file which includes adding in some nuget packages.

Currently, all I do is commit the changes in visual studio, launch GIT bash, and run the command-> git push appharbor master.  This seems to work with smaller changes that do not include adding new packages.  However, I added new packages to my project.

If I run the same command, Will this update the nuget packages I added or do I need to do more?

Also, is there a way to check whether these packages were installed on appharbor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set your packages to create a local copy, then the package will be part of your project (most of the time it is located in project/packages). If you are committing this folder to your Appharbor repository then you should be able to use the same command to update any changes. If your site is not working in Appharbor then it could be that you have those file types as part of your `.gitignore` file.